# App works when I install an apk but not when running on emulator or device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a problem in Android Studio. If I generate an apk for my app and install the apk the app works but when I run my app with an emulator or a device, I get the following error:

```
    11-21 13:20:10.248 1191-1191/com.foca.deboInventario E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.foca.deboInventario/com.foca.deboInventario.DeboInventario}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #191: Error inflating class <unknown>
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #191: Error inflating class <unknown>
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
             at com.foca.deboInventario.DeboInventario.onCreate(DeboInventario.java:162)
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256) 
             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867) 
             at com.foca.deboInventario.DeboInventario.onCreate(DeboInventario.java:162) 
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
       Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02000e a=-1 r=0x7f02000e}
             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1897)
             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256) 
             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867) 
             at com.foca.deboInventario.DeboInventario.onCreate(DeboInventario.java:162) 
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
             at 

dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-21 13:20:10.298 152-152/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.foca.deboInventario/.DeboInventario
11-21 13:20:10.408 1191-1194/com.foca.deboInventario D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 340K, 4% free 10837K/11271K, paused 20ms+15ms, total 140ms
11-21 13:20:10.738 152-155/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 841K, 15% free 17081K/19911K, paused 23ms+24ms, total 296ms
11-21 13:20:10.919 152-166/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{416ab440 com.foca.deboInventario/.DeboInventario}
11-21 13:20:11.008 262-262/com.android.launcher W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-21 13:20:12.858 1191-1191/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1191 SIG: 9
11-21 13:20:12.868 152-307/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.foca.deboInventario (pid 1191) has died.
11-21 13:20:12.928 152-517/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@415a1258 attribute=null
11-21 13:20:21.248 152-166/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{416ab440 com.foca.deboInventario/.DeboInventario}
```

In the `Activity`, the first print statement appears however the second does not. The `Activity` crashes on `setContentView`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("Here1");
    setContentView(R.layout.xml_deboinventario);
    System.out.println("Here2");
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_recepcion_inventario" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5px"
            android:text="@string/titulo_debo_inventario"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <!-- PRIMER BOTON - izquierda -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="200px"
                    android:layout_height="200px"
                    android:layout_margin="40px"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/DI_boton_izq"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_boton_masgrande"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_boton_grande"
                        android:layout_margin="10px"
                        android:text="@string/palabra_inventarios"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/boton_grande" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/continuar_inventarios_en_curso"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/boton_grande" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- SEGUNDO BOTON - centro -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="200px"
                    android:layout_height="200px"
                    android:layout_margin="40px"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/DI_boton_cen"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_boton_grande"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_boton_grande"
                        android:layout_margin="10px"
                        android:text="@string/empezar"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/boton_grande" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Comenzar Nuevo Inventario"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/boton_grande"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="200px"
                    android:layout_height="200px"
                    android:layout_margin="40px"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/boton_compras"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_boton_masgrande"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_boton_grande"
                        android:layout_margin="10px"
                        android:text="@string/mensaje_boton_acceso_compras"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/boton_grande" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/acceder_para_cargar_las_compras"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/boton_grande" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="200px"
                    android:layout_height="200px"
                    android:layout_margin="40px"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_boton_grande"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_boton_grande"
                        android:layout_margin="10px"
                        android:text="@string/empezar"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/boton_grande" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/comenzar_nuevo_inventario"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/boton_grande" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DI_version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/palabra_version"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12px"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DI_idtablet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/palabra_id_terminal"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DI_imagen_debo"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:contentDescription=""
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DI_imagen_salir"
        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/boton_salir"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DI_imagen_config"
        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10px"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/DI_imagen_salir"
        android:src="@drawable/boton_config"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DI_imagen_update"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="6px"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/DI_imagen_config"
        android:src="@drawable/boton_update"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I gave `android:background` a color but still get the same issue. 
I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Can someone tell me what is the problem and how to solve this issue?
Could this be due to an update in Android Studio?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems the error is in your xml that you are trying to inflate, post the xml code . Can you please confirm "    android:background="@drawable/fondo_recepcion_inventario"
" is available in the drawable folder

Comment: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02000e a=-1 r=0x7f02000e} the background is not a drawable/color

Comment: Are you using any dynamic drawables for buttons? If yes, then please add that code also.

Comment: Yes, is avalible. In drawable appears fondo_recepcion_inventario.png (hdpi)

Comment: All code xml agregated

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem. Change the version grandle.
Android studio ide update some changes and edit Grandle Scripts/build.grandle in my project.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2' Version IDE update
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' // Version before update
    }
}
```

Now i can run and debug the project again. Thanks a lot all.